# On netcode while running as a host does the hosting client object have the same ownership as the server-owned objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, server, client

I'm using netcode,  I'm doing something like the code below where an object spawned by either condition has the same owner id. I have only one connected client which is also the server. I'm running this code on the server side.

```cs
    GameObject gamePlayer = Instantiate(playerPreferb);
    if (condition)
    {
        gamePlayer.GetComponent<NetworkObject().SpawnWithOwnership(m_NetworkManager.ConnectedClients[0].ClientId); 
    }
    else 
    {
        gamePlayer.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(); 
    }
```

I expect it to have a different owner id, Is this intentional? Is there any way to distinguish ownership of the hosting client-owned and server-owned game objects?

Answer (score 0):

From [NetworkObject](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/basics/networkobject/index.html)

> To decide if the local client is the owner of a NetworkObject, you can check the `NetworkBehaviour.IsOwner` property.
>
> To decide if the server owns the NetworkObject, you can check the [**`NetworkBehaviour.IsOwnedByServer`**](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/0.1.0/api/MLAPI.NetworkBehaviour/#isownedbyserver) property

I would claim/expect though that yes, if you **are** the host/server then you anyway have the full server authority over objects.

Comment: As a hosting client NetworkBehaviour.IsOwner is also true for server-owned objects. I want to be able to distinguish ownership of the hosting client-owned object on the client side.